# creating custom rewrite rules for admin pages

Tags: admin, rewrite-rules

How would I setup a custom rewrite rule to redirect /wp-admin/(page-slug).php to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=(page-slug)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I setup a custom rewrite rule to redirect /wp-admin/(page-slug).php to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=(page-slug)

You can't, WP Admin doesn't make use of the rewrite rules system like the frontend, so rewrite rules have no effect on WP Admin pages.

You can only use WP rewrite rules to map pretty URLs on to versions that take the form `index.php?var=val` where the `var` URL parameters are query parameters for the main `WP_Query`, where `index.php` is the frontend entry point